# Can we please see the off-topic details by default?

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

In the closing queue, the detailed description of the meaning of the reason to close the question is hidden by default. This is great; there is absolutely no need for me to read about what "too broad" or "duplicate" or "primarily opinion-based" mean every time. But "off-topic" has a lot more information! I generally *do* want to see, as quickly as possible, why previous close voters believed the question was off topic. Can we possibly make that visible by default?

Comment: As a bit of a workaround, if you expand the reason and leave it expanded, it seems to stay expanded when you move to the next question. So that gets you partially there at least.

Comment: @JasonC: Pretty sure that also leaves the explanation of buttons expanded, which after a few dozen reviews shouldn't be necessary much, and takes up an annoying amount of vertical space.